# primeNG p-upload how to set different name value when upload muti file at once

Tags: angular, primeng

I use p-upload upload muti file at once. HTML code as follows.

```
 <p-fileUpload name="file" url="./upload.php" (onUpload)="onUpload($event)" (uploadHandler)="uploadHandler($event,form)"
                          multiple="multiple" accept="image/*,application/*" (onBeforeUpload)="onBeforeUpload($event)"
                          chooseLabel="choose" uploadLabel="upload" cancelLabel="cancel" #form>
                <ng-template pTemplate="content">
                    <ul *ngIf="uploadedFiles.length">
                        <li *ngFor="let file of uploadedFiles">{{file.name}} - {{file.size}} bytes</li>
                    </ul>
                </ng-template>
```

After I send request, the requst playload like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarymBQWZzMTQIYWChSD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="access_token"

token_725186200
------WebKitFormBoundarymBQWZzMTQIYWChSD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; 
filename="32735073444_83b7a691dc_k.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

------WebKitFormBoundarymBQWZzMTQIYWChSD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; 
filename="32764885503_1a04915b11_k.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

------WebKitFormBoundarymBQWZzMTQIYWChSD--
```

Look at up code, the name propertys are the same . However I want **name="file1" , name="file2"** .How to  fix this? Anyone can help me? I am confused.

Comment: Please use formname.files[0]. formname.files[1] etc to access it in Javascript. That works

Comment: do u mean set formname.files[0].formname.files[1] value in TS? However, formname.files.length is not sure. It depends on user upload files number.

Comment: check this. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload

Comment: Oooooooh, i got it! Use uploadHandler event can get files Array which selected and then i can set formname.files array value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal response header you get.

The `name` property is actually the name of the HTML field in the form. You wouldn't be able to set the input field name to the each file you upload, ex: '**File1**', '**File2**'.

Check [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) docs

If you want to identify multiple files at the backend, you might use string array as name value

```
<p-fileUpload name="myfile[]
```

Comment: How to use string array as name value? I saw primeNG doc , however not show example with string array as name value.

Comment: myfile is a value name in TS file? If right , how to set myfile values?

Comment: POST /test.html HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary="boundary"

--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field1"

value1
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field2"; filename="example.txt"

value2
--boundary--
Two name value are different.

Answer (score 1):

In conclusion,
Firstly, the name property can be set same value when u use one input and request multiple files . The request playload will look like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarymBQWZzMTQIYWChSD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="access_token"

token_725186200
------WebKitFormBoundarymBQWZzMTQIYWChSD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; 
filename="32735073444_83b7a691dc_k.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

------WebKitFormBoundarymBQWZzMTQIYWChSD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; 
filename="32764885503_1a04915b11_k.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

------WebKitFormBoundarymBQWZzMTQIYWChSD--
```

Secondly, the name wouldn't be able to set the same value when use multi input and request multi files. The request will looks like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarymBQWZzMTQIYWChSD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="access_token"

token_725186200
------WebKitFormBoundarymBQWZzMTQIYWChSD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_1"; 
filename="32735073444_83b7a691dc_k.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

------WebKitFormBoundarymBQWZzMTQIYWChSD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_2"; 
filename="32764885503_1a04915b11_k.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

------WebKitFormBoundarymBQWZzMTQIYWChSD--
```

By the way, the name property value is depending on u what value u set.

Thirdly, whether use on input or multi input to upload muti files ,the server code is different.